# Problema con Merge en Rstudio (Recorre columna en dataframe)

Tags: r, rstudio

Buneas tardes, tal vez mi pregunta es muy básica, soy nuevo en el mundo de R les cuento que estoy realizando el cruce de 2 bases de datos estoy utilizando "merge", quedo de la siguiente manera:

```
BasePeS <- merge(BasePeS, BaseComision, by = "Nombre.O.Cobrador", all.x=TRUE)
```

El problema es que el "Nombre.O.Cobrador" se recorre hasta el inicio de la base, estoy utilizando merge y es la primera vez que me arroja este problema, ambas bases de datos son data.frame; anexo pantallas de como mueve toda la columna:

Antes del Merge:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Despues del Merge:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Por defecto la función `merge()` coloca la columna que has seleccionado con `by` (para realizar la union de ambos dataframes) como la primera columna de tu nuevo dataframe.

Si quieres evitar que reordene las columnas puedes utilizar:

`merge(BasePeS, BaseComision)[, union(names(BasePeS), names(BaseComision))]`

para que las columnas continuen en el mismo orden que tenían antes de fusionarlas.

Comment: Guillermo, muchas gracias, si hace el cruce sin recorrer ningun dato, pero el problema es que me deja solo las datos que encuentra y elimina todos aquellos registros que no hay coincidencia, de una base de 45,000 registros solo deja 17,500, hay forma que lo que no tenga coincidencia lo deje como NA?

Comment: Es muy buena pregunta! ¿Podrías actualizar tu pregunta con una muestra de ambas tablas? (BasePeS y BaseComision). Utilizando la funcion "head(BasePeS,10)" puedes obtener las primeras filas de tu tabla que puedes pegar en la pregunta que has hecho en StackOverflow (como si fuera código utilizando las comillas) y así es mucho más fácil reconocer de donde viene el problema.